# Организация тестов в многомодульном проекте

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

Доброго времени)) Имеется модуль A. В нем в тестовых директориях лежат тестовые сущности (не тесты). Есть модуль Б, в котором лежат тесты, которые используют тестовые сущности из модуля А. Как такое можно реализовать. Если просто подключать через implementation project то тестовые сущности не видны при сборке

Comment: да, использую gradle

Answer (score 0):

Создайте новую конфигурацию для тестовых артефактов и потом используйте ee в других модулях.

Удобно задавать конфигурацию на уровне родительского модуля, т.е. в корневом `build.gradle`:

```
configure(subprojects) {
    configurations {
        testArtifacts
    }

    task testJar (type: Jar) {
        baseName = "${project.name}-test"
        from sourceSets.test.output
    }

    artifacts {
      testArtifacts testJar
    }

}
```

Теперь в модуле `B` можно указать зависимость от `testArtifacts` из `A`:

```
dependencies {
   // существующие зависимости

   // предполагаем, что A находится по пути path/to/A от корня проекта
   testCompile project (path: ":path:to:A", configuration: 'testArtifacts')
}
```

Comment: Конфигурацию прописывать не в наследуемом модуле, а в корневом проекта?

Comment: В корневом происходит Could not get unknown property 'testJar' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultArtifactHandler. То есть нужно еще таску прописать?

Comment: Точно, недокопировал изначально.  Добавил в ответ